# How can shared references be described?

Tags: java

I am trying to understand shared references in the best way and i'm not sure i have fully understood it.

My understanding of shared references is when i have a collection and there exists two or more references to that perticular collection in the code, if it is changed in one of those references the other's will not be the same and generate errors, correct?

Regards

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "shared references". Typically, a "shared reference" means there's only one object that two or more things have a reference to. Since there's only one object, changing it through one reference has precisely the same effect as changing it through the other. But you might mean something else by "shared reference".

Comment: also am looking into Class invariants but not intrested in more - today ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if it is changed in one of those references the other's will not be the same and generate errors, correct?

Right but partially. if contents of the collection is changed through one reference, other reference will also point to the updated contents.

Your other part says, that it will generate errors. well, it depends on logic.

```
class A
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A a1 = new A();
        A a2 = a1;
        A a3 = a2;
    }
}
```

Here, all the references are pointing to same object. So, if object is modified by `a1`, other reference `a2`, `a3` will also see the modifies state.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you and your brother are at the circus and you each win a prize of a balloon and a pen. You draw a happy face on your balloon and your brother draws a sad face on his.

Right now you do **not** have shared references. Each of you can change what is drawn on your balloon without changing the other.

Sadly you accidentally let go of your balloon but your brother, because he loves you, offers to share his balloon with you so he ties a second string to it and hands that string to you. You now have **shared references** to the one balloon.

Now, whatever changes are made to the face on the balloon will be shared by both of you. There is one balloon and two strings. If you draw a happy face on the balloon you hold, your brother will also find a happy face on the balloon he is holding because they are the **same** balloon.